# Tab bar not full showing on iPhone 5 and iPhone 4

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

when I run my app on any of the simulators, it works fine.  However, when I run the app on my iPhone 5 or my friend's iPhone 4, the tab bar is shown halfway off the screen.  The icons and the actual bar aren't fully shown.  I've tried changing the size of the view controllers, aswell as checking ANY full screen options.
  Thanks,

[My iPhone's view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JNGK.jpg)
[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOSbj.jpg)

Comment: set the size and check constraint so that the app will run perfect on both

Comment: Sure you're not running on the iPad simulator vs. iPhone device?

Comment: Nope, I'm definitely running on iPhone 4-inch screen simulator.

Comment: How do I find the constraints? also it works fine on the iPhone 4-inch simulator but not on my iPhone 5 (4-inch screen too?)

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: @WECorps can you post some screen shots from IB and simulator/device

Comment: posted some links to the pictures, as I don't have the 'reputation' to post them directly... also I'm using storyboards

Comment: It looks like your icons for the tab bar are too big.  Check the requirements on the sizes and make sure you add the correct size as well as the @2x icon.

Comment: make one icon 30 x 30 and the @2x 60 x 60.

Comment: and what is the view size?

Comment: @WECorps, did you ever figure this out?  Just want to know if it was the tab bar or the size of the icons.  Let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Consolidated from comments:

set the size and check constraint so that the app will run perfect on both

Turn off auto-layout: do so by pressing <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>commadnd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

If you are using iOS 7, it does some funky things with the layout, you should ensure that the interface has enough padding for the system title bar (don't place it at the very top), etc.

Comment: how do I check constraints? I can't find it anywhere.  Also is there anyway I can adjust the placement of the tab bar? Everything else (navigation bars, title bars, maps etc.) works fine, even my table cell view.  Also How do I adjust padding?

Comment: this document describes how to deal with the new editor. http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2014/03/10/autolayout-in-interface-builder-xcode-5-dot-1/ and by padding, I simply mean, moving the objects around to leave space.